# How to change Beamer note page background color?

Tags: beamer

I understand that in beamer environment I can have some presenter's notes by adding

```
\setbeameroption{show notes}
```

and put all my notes in `\note{blah blah ...}`. It will give me a note page with grey background and a header. I want to know if I can change the background color, e.g. to white?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To add to @TorbjornT.'s answer, the Beamer color template defines three elements for specifying colors of the note page: `note page`, `note title`, and `note date`, where

- `note page` defines the background and foreground colors of the note page
- `note title` defines the colors for the "title bar" of the note page
- `note date` defines the colors for the date entry

The default settings are

```
\setbeamercolor{note page}{bg=white!90!black, fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{note title}{bg=white!80!black, fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{note date}{parent=note title}
```

To change the background colors, simply redefine the colors of those elements.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeameroption{show notes}

\setbeamercolor{note page}{bg=green}
\setbeamercolor{note title}{bg=red}
\setbeamercolor{note date}{fg=yellow}

\begin{document}
\section{section}
\subsection{subsection}
\begin{frame}{frame title}
A frame.
\note{This is a note for presenter.}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

## Output (of note page)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is a partial answer at least. The background of the text area (not the header) can be set with

```
\setbeamercolor{note page}{bg=white}
```

changing `white` to whatever color you like.

Another option is to change the template used for the note pages, `plain` is text on a white background, no header:

```
\setbeamertemplate{note page}{plain}
```

I haven't figured out how to keep the header and change its background colour. Minimal example.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeameroption{show notes}
\setbeamercolor{note page}{bg=white}
% \setbeamertemplate{note page}{plain} 
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Text\note{note}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```