# Beamer - remove the header of notes section but keep the background color

Tags: beamer, pdftex

I'd like to remove the header of Beamer's notes section but would like to keep the gray background color to distinguish it from slides. May I ask how to do this?

I found this thread ([Notes on the side of beamer slides](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/419864/notes-on-the-side-of-beamer-slides)) which showed how to remove the header. But when I followed their suggestion, the background color became white.

I also tried this thread's suggestions ([How to change Beamer note page background color?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154271/how-to-change-beamer-note-page-background-color)), but it didn't work once I removed the header.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=bottom}

\setbeamertemplate{note page}{\insertnote}
\setbeamercolor{note page}{bg=white!90!black, fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{note title}{bg=white!80!black, fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{note date}{parent=note title}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
This is my slides.
\note{This is my notes. The background color should be gray to distinguish it from slides.}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Output (the 2nd slide's background color should be gray):

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of the `tcolorbox` package

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{note box}{enhanced,
                 height=\paperheight,
                 frame hidden,
                 boxrule=0mm,
                 colback=bg, % note background color defined by beamer 
                 arc=0mm,
                 grow to left by=1cm,
                 grow to right by=1cm,
                  }
                  
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=bottom}

%\setbeamercolor{note page}{bg=white!90!black, fg=black}
%\setbeamercolor{note title}{bg=white!80!black, fg=black}
\setbeamertemplate{note page}{% 
               \begin{note box}
                 \insertnote
               \end{note box}
}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
This is my slides.
\note{This is my notes. The background color should be gray to distinguish it from slides. }
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you - it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Here a a MWE that is based off of how beamer itself draws the background color for the note page (i.e. without invoking any other packages):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}

\setbeamercolor{note page}{bg=gray, fg=white}
\setbeamertemplate{note page}{%
    % adds in bg color
        \insertvrule{\paperheight}{note page.bg}%
        \vskip-\paperheight%
    % changes font color
        \usebeamercolor[fg]{note page}%
    % inserts note
        \insertnote%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
This will be on my slides.
\note{This will be my notes. The background color will be gray to distinguish it from slides. }
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! This also works very well!